# HttpWebRequest Odd Behavior

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am doing a HTTPWebRequest to an image stored on a website using the code below -

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

The "url" here is read from an Excel file or a txt file. I am noticing something really strange here.

When I try to read from the files, some of the requests time out. But when I take one of the failing URLs and put it directly into the "Create()" function, the request goes through and is completed in some milliseconds.

I have checked the format of the strings and values that are getting passed to the request and they seem identical to what I hard-coded.

The failures happen for jpg, htm, png files but doesn't happen for pdf or gif files. There are no failures when I hardcode these URLs

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].